# Управление елементом в списке

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview

Нужно сделать в элементе списка анимацию. Проблема в следующем я определил `OnClickListener` в адаптере, но это не совсем подходит, потому как он срабатывает почему то только на двух последних элементах. А если определить `OnItemClickListener` в фрагменте в котором я использую listView с адаптером, то не понятно как вызвать нужную мне функцию в элементе списка, к примеру запустить анимацию в конкретном айтеме, после чего при повтором нажатии должна выполниться другая анимация, т.е. нужно хранить состояние айтема.
Для наглядности вот элемент списка с кнопкой которая появляется и скрывается с правого края:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** как такое лучше всего реализовать? И что лучше использовать для таких задач, может RecyclerView?

Не уверен что он тут нужен, но вот код адаптера:

**ContactListAdapter.java**

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;


ArrayList<String> list;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutParent;


public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> contactList) {
    this.context = context;
    list = contactList;
    layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rootView = convertView;
    String contactName = (String) getItem(position);

    if (rootView == null) {

        rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contact_list_item, parent, false);

        relativeLayoutParent = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_parent);


        relativeLayoutParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something
            }
        });

    }

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тема уже заезжена много раз. При использовании `BaseAdapter` используйте паттерн `ViewHolder`

```
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View rootView = convertView;
        String contactName = (String) getItem(position);

        if (rootView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contact_list_item, null);
                holder.relativeLayoutParent = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_parent);
                //Сюда через холдер добавьте еще необходимые вьюшки
                rootView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) rootView.getTag();
            }

               holder.relativeLayoutParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do something
                }
            });


            return rootView ;

        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
            RelativeLayout relativeLayoutParent;
            //Сюда еще ваш TextView добавите
        }
```

Comment: Это то что мне нужно, спасибо. Не знаете почему могла поплыть верстка после применения данного адаптера  и збился порядок элементов в списки